# how to change default tagprefix in user control

Tags: asp.net

When you drag a web user control onto your design surface, it will automatically assigns the tagprefix = uc1.

Does anyone know how to change the default tagprefix for all web user controls
you drag onto a web form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Adding User Controls to a Web Forms Page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d0t5fak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You have to `Register` the control below the `Page directive` like below.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Guest" TagName="GuestExample" Src="~/YourControl.ascx" %>
```

and then change the `TagPrefix` and `TagName` as per your requirement.

Example

```
<Guest:GuestExample ID="ID" runat="server" />
```

---

[image]

---

> Instead of duplicating them on all your pages, just declare them once
>   within the new pages->controls section with the web.config file of
>   your application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="Guest" src="~/YourControl.ascx" tagName="GuestExample"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This method also can work but this is no I want.. I want when drag out user control,it will automatically assigns what I assign tagprefix

Comment: In order to set the `TagPrefix` and `TagName` of the `UserControl`. It is required to register the control first. `Drag Drop` the `WebUserControl` will convert it into `Anchor` tag.

Comment: In case register duplication is not required in each page. Use `Web.config` and reuse it in all pages as mentioned above.

Comment: It is not possible to do that. We just have a couple of options. `1. Write the control registration in Web.config and another way is register the control in each page. Now choice is yours.`

Answer (score 2):

Actually this can be achieved using an Assembly-Level attribute, TagPrefix.

```vb
<Assembly: TagPrefix("MyCompany.Web", "SomeFancyTagPrefix")> 

Public Class MyCustomControl
    Inherits WebControl

        'class implementation

End Class
```

The first parameter is the namespace of the control, and the second is the tag prefix you'd prefer.

The result when dragging and dropping your custom control onto the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyCompany.Web.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="My Company" Namespace="MyCompany.Web" TagPrefix="SomeFancyTagPrefix" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <SomeFancyTagPrefix:MyCustomControl ID="MyCustomControl1" runat="server">
        </SomeFancyTagPrefix:MyCustomControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```